# $scope variable not changing in controller when changed using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, materialize

I tried in all ways (keeping the scope to false, etc but not able to change my scope in controller),am I missing something.

directive:

```
angular.module("ui.materialize.inputfield", [])
        .directive('inputField', ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {
            return {
                transclude: true,
                scope: {},
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        Materialize.updateTextFields();

                        // The "> > [selector]", is to restrict to only those tags that are direct children of the directive element. Otherwise we might hit to many elements with the selectors.

                        // Triggering autoresize of the textareas.
                        element.find("> > .materialize-textarea").each(function () {
                            var that = $(this);
                            that.addClass("materialize-textarea");
                            that.trigger("autoresize");
                            var model = that.attr("ng-model");
                            if (model) {

                                scope.$parent.$watch(model, function (a, b) {

                                    if (a !== b) {
                                        $timeout(function () {

                                            that.trigger("autoresize");
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        // Adding char-counters.
                        element.find('> > .materialize-textarea, > > input').each(function (index, countable) {
                            countable = angular.element(countable);
                            if (!countable.siblings('span[class="character-counter"]').length) {
                                countable.characterCounter();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                template: '<div ng-transclude class="input-field"></div>'
            };
        }]);
```

and here is my view

```
<div ng-controller="Example Controller"
<div input-field class="col l3">
    <input type="text" ng-model="class1" length="150">
    <label>Class</label>
    {{class1}}
</div>
{{class1}}
</div>
```

I see that only class1 of the directive scope is changing but not the last class1,

if I initialize my controller with $scope.class1 = 9
only the first class1 is changing but not the second class1.Can any one help me regarding the problem

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to use `controllerAs` syntax in your view.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController as ctrl"
    <div input-field class="col l3">
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.class1" length="150">
        <label>Class</label>
        {{ ctrl.class1 }}
    </div>
    {{ ctrl.class1 }}
</div>
```

In your controller, instead of attaching properties to the `$scope`, you attach it directly to your controller instance.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ExampleController', function () {
        var vm = this; // vm stands for View-Model and is reference to current controller instance

        vm.class1 = 'some class';
    });
```

This makes sure you are dealing with the same controller property `class1` everywhere.

To understand why this works, read this documentation on how scope works in Angular

[Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: if scope variable is changed dynamically we can bind it to view using $watch or $apply,but what can we do to bind the view of {{ctrl.variable}} to the new value,when it is changed in the controller dynamically?

Comment: Angular attaches the controller instance to the $scope with the given alias as the $scope property. So, $scope.ctrl in my example is the instance of the controller. You can then $watch like you normally would watch any $scope property. 

$scope.$watch('ctrl.class1', someListenerFunction);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160209/getting-parent-index-inside-a-custom-directice can you help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is working on the div it is set on, and the second class1 is outside of that div,and hence outside of the scope of your directive.

Comment: I understood that,but how can I change my code so that it can change the variable outside the scope of my directive

Comment: @Maarteen can you help regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160209/getting-parent-index-inside-a-custom-directice

Answer (score 0):

never use primitve type model.always use with dot property.

change the ng-model from class to form1.class1

Comment: but I find this not working for nested dot properties,(example: form1.class1.section is giving the same trouble

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160209/getting-parent-index-inside-a-custom-directice can you help regarding this